# jQuery UI Auto suggest select issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default

My data

```
[{"icd_ID":"2","icd_code":"A00","icd_desc":"Cholera","icd_yn":"N"},
        {"icd_ID":"3","icd_code":"A00.0","icd_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholere","icd_yn":"Y"},
        {"icd_ID":"4","icd_code":"A00.1","icd_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor","icd_yn":"Y"},
        {"icd_ID":"5","icd_code":"A00.9","icd_desc":"Cholera, unspecified","icd_yn":"Y"}
        ]
```

For "icd_desc" auto suggest value , i want to get "icd_code".

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ajaypatel_aj/PRnc9/

Comment: So you want to search on `icd_desc` but you want the input to be populated with `icd_code`? Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a local data source, I would transform that data source to conform with what the widget expects:

```
var source = $.map(availableTags1, function (el) {
    return {
        label: el.icd_desc,
        value: el.icd_code
    };
 });

 $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: source
 });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sXaZX/

Comment: Hay @Andrew Whitaker Can you please help me in this case, Suppose i have more than 10,000 records, for one search i get 100 results but i want to show only 10. How it is possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you coding this with server side script? The local data is in the response when you request a  page right? so just split out 10 items

Comment: No local side, i did it Thanks :)